# Unable to load web part script resources

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts

I am getting an error on the latest SPFx framework. I have created a web part, updating the `cdnBasePath` in `write-manifests.json`.

I added the resource files to a document library and deployed the app. When the web part renders I get the error message:

> [SPWebPartErrorCode.ScriptLoadError]:: MESSAGE:: Unable to load web part script resources due to: Error: p Error loading https://placeholder-base-url/e8336591-8934-4d69-82f0-473718ec946e.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

No idea what changed but a `gulp nuke`, `gulp bundle` and `gulp package-solution` seems to have fixed it.

Comment: I'm curious where you are using SPFx. Are you on a separete developer tenant? or you already have this update on the production tenant?

Comment: I am using a developer tenant.